# Error when replacing `unknown` with more specific type in function parameters

Tags: typescript

In the codebase I'm working on, it makes sense to have a generalised type that includes a function with a parameter of type `unknown`. Then wherever that type is used, narrow the function's parameter type to something more specific. However, this raises an error like:

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type Foo
```

Following is some simple code to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```js
interface Foo {
  func: (arg0: unknown) => number;
}

type SolidType = {
  someNumber: number;
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
  func: (arg0: SolidType) => number;
}

const x: Bar = {
  func: (arg0) => {
    return arg0.someNumber;
  }
}
```

The above code raises the following error:

```
Interface 'Bar' incorrectly extends interface 'Foo'.
  Types of property 'func' are incompatible.
    Type '(arg0: SolidType) => number' is not assignable to type '(arg0: unknown) => number'.
      Types of parameters 'arg0' and 'arg0' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'SolidType'.ts(2430)
```

Why is it not possible to override an `unknown` with a specific type in this case? Am I using `unknown` incorrectly here, and if so is there a better alternative?

Comment: It's not possible since it's not safe; if `Bar` extends `Foo` then I should be able to use a `Bar` anywhere a `Foo` is required.  [Imagine](//tsplay.dev/W4p1KW) `function takeFoo(foo: Foo) {  foo.func("this is fine"); }`.  Is `x` a `Foo` or not?  If so, then I should be able to call `takeFoo(x)`, but that would do bad things at runtime.  That's why `class Bar extends Foo` is an error.  If you don't care about safety then use `any` instead of `unknown` like [this](//tsplay.dev/Na0j9w). If you care about safety then use `never` like [this](//tsplay.dev/Wzod4w). Can you elaborate on the use case?

Comment: I mean, could you show some example uses of `Foo` where you don't know it's of type `Bar`?  What can you do with the base class?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment @jcalz. In the actual code `Foo` is a type that modules use to describe how to build JSON:API resources, it has 3 generics (for data structure, filters and attributes). The problem is `Foo` can contain other `Foo`s (with different structure, filters and attributes), for example `func` is an argument that can take `Foo`s with different type arguments than the current one. I don't _think_ Generics can be twisted to my use case, hence I thought of using a general datatype that could be narrowed instead.

Comment: @jcalz is this enough to go on, would a TS Playground link help?

Comment: A TS Playground link is almost always helpful!

Comment: @jcalz Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/wRJv7w, I cut down my code a lot but it's still quite long, relevant bits are at the top and bottom

Comment: Again, if you change `unknown` to `any` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqvbqW) or to `never` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2Kr1N), does it work for your use cases?  There's only one defined value of `makeRelationshipsObject` and you haven't *used* it so it's not clear what the use case is.  Since most of the code you included isn't relevant (according to you), you should probably remove more of it so that the [mre] is sufficiently minimal, and then add some code to make it complete by showing why you are using `unknown` instead of `any` or `never`.

Comment: @jcalz "Since most of the code you included isn't relevant (according to you)"
Sorry wrong word. It is relevant, I meant: the parts you should probably look at first are at the top and bottom, while what's in-between is important for understanding the context of what I'm trying to do. I already attempted to make a minimal example in the OP, but it didn't convey enough of the context.

Anyway, I think `never` is an okay solution here. Thanks for that! I'm wondering if some sort of recursive Generics might work as well though, will have to think about it :)

Comment: @jcalz Feel free to post an answer to the OP using `never` and I'll accept it

Comment: Okay, I'm answering based on the `Foo` and `Bar` example, and you can translate that to your own code as I showed in your more recent playground link.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [the `--strictFunctionTypes` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) enabled, the compiler protects you against unsafe function types by checking their parameter types [*contravariantly*](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance), which means that a function type `(a: X) => void` extends (or "is assignable to" or "is a subtype of") a function type `(a: Y) => void` if and only if `Y` extends `X`.  Note that the assignability direction changes for the function type compared to that of its parameter type.  That is, function types *vary* *counter* to their parameter types.  In other words, they *contra-vary*.

Why does type safety require this?  It has to do with direction of data flow.  When data flows from a source to a target, the type the source sends must extend the type the target accepts.  The source can safely get narrower (e.g., "I claimed to give you a `Fruit`, and I'm actually giving you a `Banana`") and the target can safely get wider (e.g., "you gave me a `Fruit`, and I'd actually accept any `Food` whatsoever").  It is unsafe for the source to get wider (e.g., "I claimed to give you a `Fruit`, but I'm actually giving you some `Food` which may or may not be a `Fruit`, I don't know, sorry) or for the target to get narrower (e.g., "you gave me a `Fruit`, but I really only accept a `Banana` and maybe you gave me something else, so I'm not satisfied")

When you pass data into a function parameter, the function is receiving the data, and thus the parameter type can be safely widened, not narrowed.

---

Let's examine your case:

```
interface Foo {
  func: (arg0: unknown) => number;
}
```

Here, `Foo`'s `func()` method apparently, right off the bat, claims to accept an argument of type `unknown`.  That means it is already as wide as it can possibly be.  Callers of `func()` can pass in anything whatsoever that they like:

```
function takeFoo(foo: Foo) { foo.func("this is fine"); }
```

But your definition of `Bar` does this:

```
interface Bar {
  func: (arg0: SolidType) => number;
}
```

Any value of type `Bar` is free to expect that its `func()` method will be called with a `SolidType`:

```
const x: Bar = {
  func: (arg0) => {
    return Number(arg0.someNumber.toFixed(2));
  }
}
```

If `Bar extends Foo` were true, it would require that the following line should be just fine:

```
takeFoo(x) // <-- this should be allowed if Bar extends Foo
```

But of course at runtime, this would fail with `arg0.someNumber is undefined`.

By saying `Bar extends Foo`, you are unsafely narrowing the function parameter of `func()` from `unknown` ("I'll take anything!") to `SolidType` ("I lied when I said I'd take anything, sorry!").

---

So, how to fix it?  Well, it really depends strongly on your use cases.

If you have a `Foo` that isn't known to be of some specific intended subtype like `Bar`, will you ever call its `func()` method?  Do you really plan on supporting `foo.func("this is fine")` and `foo.func(123)` and `foo.func(new Date())`?  I'm guessing not, and that you will only actually call `func()` if you have some specific subtype.  In this case, it means that you might want to say that `func`'s parameter should be the *narrowest possible type*, which is [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type):

```
interface Foo {
  func: (arg0: never) => number;
}
```

Now your subtype works with no error:

```
interface Bar extends Foo {
  func: (arg0: SolidType) => number; // okay, no error
}
```

And the `takeFoo()` from above is no longer valid, so you don't have to worry about someone mistaking a `Bar` for something that accepts any possible `arg0`:

```
function takeFoo(foo: Foo) { foo.func("this is fine"); } // error
// ---------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

If your use case requires some particular behavior with `func()` on the base type `Foo`, then you might have to tweak `never` to something else.  In order to be type safe though, subtype function parameters can get wider but not narrower.  If you find that you really need the opposite, then you might choose to give up type safety by using something like [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) instead of `never`.  That could lead to `takeFoo()`-style runtime errors, so you'd need to be careful, which is always true when you intentionally loosen type safety.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJJDYAFwjQDMFkAxAe0byJJOoFdh4AuJABQg0WAAz9uAa2CMA7sACUSALwA+JME5gARlQDcbJAF8ih8gE8YyAMqMANhgAmAFUvJlrYuyiNIAOS1dNH5NHX1DE0JDMkoaOiQAIWEkCAAPSmBHKCQmFgIvDm4+QWExflsHFzclNQ1A8K9Iwy4ecgxGYCRyEEkIXIFqZn5cpVwkQcYAOhb4AQAicgALDGyV8bIIOYU9Y1MveA6ociRU-iS0FU92caL+IRFRGvV865I0CHJONE6AsLR7sSTHz+epoSbkRj0DCpCCOAQAJgU20MJEiqL2JHIaHMV3Y3V6-VSSgA9MSkAAeAC0lK6y2yUEWjE4dkcSF0SBAdjsclhpGoiWSaQyWRyzAiSHgIHI8EWgggoxREsO9ggk25WAE8oiRCahFAkFg8T8EAAblRcTEqLREKK8oqZndSuINKaqE86n8DI0MV03EgKk5XFZLi9vL4IL8giFQV70VEvJa4jbzil0hBMtlcrjCjxHQ9yvZA9UVOpQkFY7t4zn4G0Ol0en1mAMhrbRuNmNMivMlms1tQNlsdmikKSUmg0IwLosqBAfQdgEcTmdkh5Q9W82J3Wv2O9Pt8kJGqADREDw4ewRCoTC4YjkQVK3G9jqgA)

Comment: That link is gold. It really helped me understand covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Generic types here instead of `unknown`.
For example:

```
interface Foo<T> {
  func: (arg0: T) => number;
}

type SolidType = {
  someNumber: number;
}

interface Bar extends Foo<SolidType> {
  func: (arg0: SolidType) => number;
}

const x: Bar = {
  func: (arg0) => {
    return arg0.someNumber;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, that won't work, there's a lot of context here that would be tedious to explain. I am using generics for other things, but in this case they're not a good fit